# Why does my GLSL shader fail compilation with no error message?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, glfw

I'm building a game using OpenGL and C++. I'm using GLFW and GLAD. I'm currently in the process of setting up simple shaders, but I'm completely roadblocked by a compilation problem. In a nutshell, **shader compilation fails with no error message**.

Here's my vertex shader (it's meant to draw 2D images and text):

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 vPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 vTexCoords;
layout (location = 2) in vec4 vColor;

out vec4 fColor;
out vec2 fTexCoords;

uniform mat4 mvp;

void main()
{
    vec4 position = mvp * vec4(vPosition, 0, 1);
    position.y *= -1;

    gl_Position = position;
    fColor = vColor;
    fTexCoords = vTexCoords;
}
```

And here's the relevant code to create the shader, load the shader source, compile the shader, and check for errors.

```cpp
GLuint shaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

std::string source = FileUtilities::ReadAllText(Paths::Shaders + filename);

GLchar const* file = source.c_str();
GLint length = static_cast<GLint>(source.size());

glShaderSource(shaderId, 0, &file, &length);
glCompileShader(shaderId);

GLint status;

glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);

if (status == GL_FALSE)
{
    GLint logSize = 0;

    glGetShaderiv(shaderId, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logSize);

    std::vector<GLchar> message = std::vector<GLchar>(logSize);

    glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderId, logSize, nullptr, &message[0]);
    glDeleteShader(shaderId);

    std::cout << std::string(message.begin(), message.end());
}
```

Using that code, `logSize` is returned as 1, meaning that I'm unable to access the error message provided by GL. From what I can tell, the message doesn't exist at all. I've already seen the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291314/unable-to-retrieve-an-error-message-from-glgetshaderinfolog), in which the issue was a missing call to `glCompileShader`. As you can see, my code does call that function.

In attempting to solve this problem, I've already confirmed a few things.

- My shader source (a string) is being read correctly. The source is a single string that, as far as I can tell, exactly matches the actual shader file.
- There are no casting issues from the string source to `GLchar const*` or `GLint` (the variables `file` and `length`). Both look correct.
- If I artificially inflate the value of `logSize` (to, say, 1000), the resulting message is nothing but zeroes. No error message exists.
- I am calling `glfwInit()` and related functions before reaching this point in the code. Querying `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` does correctly return the target version (3.3.0).

Does anyone know how to fix this? As I said, my progress is completely blocked since I can't render anything (2D or 3D) without working shaders.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you never upload any shader source to the shader.

The second parameter in this line:

```
glShaderSource(shaderId, 0, &file, &length);
```

tells OpenGL to load 0 code strings to the shader (nothing). Change this to 1, and it should work.

Comment: Wow. Nice catch. Still my fault, but it's pretty frustrating that GL doesn't generate an error for passing zero. It's also strange to me that the shader isn't compiled anyway, given that the source code string is valid.

Comment: Well that wouldn't really make sense either. The third param is a list of shader sources. I believe this is so that you can create a template (such as utility functions), that can be included in any shader you want, increasing code re-usability.